# When I using dynamic_cast it gives error?

Tags: c++, linux

When I use `dynamic_cast()` it gives following error:

> error: 'dynamic_cast' was not declared in this scope

thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you mistype the error message, or did you mistype it in the code?     Could you show the code?

Comment: I think, you need to read documentation - http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/ - dynamic_cast section . There is no function with name "dynamic_cast"

Comment: Two of the three places you've used `dynamic_cast` in your question, you've spelled it wrong. Spelling is important in programming.

Answer (score 7):

the syntax is as follows

```
dynamic_cast<TargetType>(SourceObject)
```

in the error msg you provide, there is a typo (dyanmic vs dynamic)

Answer (score 1):

`dynamic_cast` works ONLY with polymorphic class. So if the class you're working with is not polymorphic, it will give compilation error.

Polymorphic class is one which has one atleast one virtual function, even be it destructor!

The syntax of using `dynamic_cast` is in this example:

```
struct A { virtual ~A(){} };
struct B : A { };

B b;
A *pA = &b; //no cast needed here!
B *pB = dynamic_cast<B*>(pA); // dynamic cast is needed here!
```

Comment: Absolutely correct. But in this case it would have given a different compilation error

Comment: @Armen: What compilation error? At what line? See this : http://www.ideone.com/07Jyg

Comment: @Nawaz: I mean if the problem was the fact that nonpolymorphic types were dynamic_cast, the error wouldn't say that dynamic_cast is undeclared identifier. Sorry for misphrasing

Comment: @Armen: Sorry, your comment doesn't make sense. Could you rephrase it again?

Comment: @Nawaz: Yes, of course. The OP tells us that he gets an error that dynamic_cast is undeclared identifier. Your answer tells him that if you use dynamic_cast with nonpolymorphic types, you'll get a compile error. My point is that although you WILL get an error, it won't say that dynamic_cast is undeclared. Clear now? :)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is `dynamic_cast<Foo*>(BarObj);`, so it's not called as a function.

Comment: Looks like a call to an explicit specialisation of a template function... It could be implemented as a function call or handled specially by the compiler.